# Php mail allows me to send the data to my email but I don't receive any email

Tags: php, email

I want to be able to collect all the data from the form of my site that is already live and send it to my email.

I based myself in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail) and adjusted my php based on that. However, when I click on submit button, the fields get empty but when I check my email I receive nothing.

How can I collect the data from the site and send to my email?

My code looks like this:

```
<form role="form" method="POST">
    <br style="clear:both">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Contact a Conveyancing Property Lawyer Now</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Contact Number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <select name="situation" id="situation">
        <option value="Unemployed">Unemployed</option>
        <option value="Employed">Employed</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $situation = $_POST['situation'];
            $from = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
            $to = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
            $subject = '$subject';

            $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Mobile:\n $mobile Subject: $subject\n Situation:\n $situation";

            // set content-type when sending HTML email
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            // More headers optional/headers 
            $headers .= "From:$from";

            if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
            } else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
            }
        }   
    ?>
 </form>
```

Comment: Try `SMTP` mailer [Reference](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Check if your mail function sends the mail correctly. Set an `echo $result` behinde your `if(mail(...))`. Run the script on your local maschine? If yes set up your mail server, to send mails or look for an test mail server, to simulate the mail transfer.

Comment: I just noticed that the code actually works, but it takes too long for me to receive the email. The only thing I see in the email is that all is printed in one line, meaning that the \n is being ignored

Answer (score 0):

PHP requires an installed and running mail system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file.

Comment: was never aware of it. hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

First you need change your PHP mail configuration:

1. Open your php.ini file.
2. Search [mail function].
3. Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP.
4. Save the php.ini file.
5. Restart your server.

You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) For mail

this is probably the world's most popular code for sending email from PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is perfect. i checked it after some small changes, Like you put $subject in single quotation marks which is wrong , and you also forgot to print the output which is $result . other wise your code is perfect.

Run this code, if it shows error then please enable SEND MAIL option to your server.

```
<form role="form" method="POST">
    <br style="clear:both">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Contact a Conveyancing Property Lawyer Now</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Contact Number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <select name="situation" id="situation">
        <option value="Unemployed">Unemployed</option>
        <option value="Employed">Employed</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $situation = $_POST['situation'];
            $from = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
            $to = 'sidney@web2web.co.za'; 
            $subject = $subject;

            $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Mobile:\n $mobile Subject: $subject\n Situation:\n $situation";

            // set content-type when sending HTML email
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            // More headers optional/headers 
            $headers .= "From:$from";

            if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
            } else {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
            }
            echo $result;
        }   
    ?>
```